# Google endpoints can't request HTTP PATCH at localhost

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Google auto-generates and HTTP PATCH endpoint when you code an HTTP PUT
But this PATCH endpoint doesn't run at localhost
The HTTP answer error code is 404

At GAE production server you don't have any problem
It makes himself, two consecutive calls: GET and PUT

Anyone is running PATCH at localhost ?

Answer (score 1):

I planned to use that (and MERGE as well) but will now be careful. GET followed by PUT looks like a hacky workaround.  Unfortunately all you can do is add your star to [Support for HTTP PATCH](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4359) and similar feature requests, and try to lobby others to do the same (I've added my vote).

Away from the Endpoint library I hope to implement doPatch and doMerge in an OpenData compatible servlet, and then hope that Jetty connects the HTTP requests from jQuery ajax to those methods.  You might be able to try something similar by editing the generated Endpoint library, but that approach might encounter more problems.  I'd appreciate feedback on how you fare.